# neo4j V2.0.0 M5 "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: nullpointerexception, neo4j, cypher

After upgrading to Neo4j V2.0.0 M5 I ran into the subject error when running a cypher query in my web app. To isolate the issue, I tried the following similar queries in the basic Neo4j console (http://console.neo4j.org/) as follows:

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name ='Neo' 
RETURN n
```

Result: (6 {name:"Neo"})

Next tested match on regular expression using "=~"

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name =~'Neo.*' 
RETURN n
```

Result: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Next tested on case insensitive by pre-pending a regular expression with (?i)

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name =~'(?i)Neo' 
RETURN n
```

Result: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

And finally tested for both regex and case insensitivity with =~ '(?i)neo.*'

```
MATCH n 
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)neo.*' 
RETURN n
```

Result: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

I believe the issue is with "=~." Can anyone else recreate these errors? Shouldn't all of these queries resulted in returning the "Neo" node? If not, please let me know why.

Thank you,

Jeff

Comment: Neo4j tells me that this is a bug in this milestone release. I was warned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great people at Neo4j tell me that this is a milestone release bug. As with all milestone releases, we were warned. Reverting back to Neo4j Stable Release 1.9.3 and will test with M6.